# Как выравнять текст с иконкой

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.promo-list{
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}

.promo-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 26px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.promo-text {    
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="promo-list">
           <li>
               <div class="promo-icon">
                 <img src="../Diplom/img/megaphone%201.svg">
               </div>
               <span class="promo-text">Персональные предложения в мобильном приложении</span>
           </li>
           <li>
               <div class="promo-icon">
                 <img src="../Diplom/img//gift%20(3)%201.svg">
               </div>
               <span class="promo-text">Широкий ассортимент товаров</span>
           </li>
            <li>
               <div class="promo-icon">
                 <img src="../Diplom/img/delivery-truck%201.svg">
               </div>
               <span class="promo-text">Быстрая доставка</span>
           </li>
       </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```
li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Проверяйте то, что пишите, нет такого параметра `dlex` у свойства `display`.

Comment: @De.Minov да, поправил